# Factories.rb file is not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following ruby on rails tutorials 3.2 by Michael Hartl but when i put `gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'` in my gemfile and run `bundle install` it shows "bundle complete" as the gem is already loaded in my PC. My problem is it's not generating the `factories.rb` file in spec folder. What is going wrong?

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',          '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby',    '3.0.1'

group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.5'
   gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
   gem 'annotate',    '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',     '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',           '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

`routes.rb`:

```
SAMPLEApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

Comment: thank you very much Holger Just fro editing

Comment: nothing to worry guys i just sorted out the error

Answer (score 2):

Running `bundle install` won't add any files to your Rails application. It will just download the proper libraries that it needs to use.  Sometimes these libraries will come with a rails generator and you would run something like `rails generate some_library:install`. I don't think that's the case with factory_girl_rails. You probably need to add the file manually.

Comment: If rspec and FG are installed, standard generators create spec/factories/modelname.rb. But it's the only thing that's created automatically

Comment: `factories.rb` is created by RSpec I guess.

Comment: in my case factories.rb is not created so i made my own factories.rb file and run the test and the test is passed just now